# How to Remove this error try different solutions but can't

Tags: python, django

ImportError at /

No module named forms

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.6.11
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:

No module named forms

Exception Location:     /home/zaheer/django-user/login/myapp/views.py in , line 11
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:

['/home/zaheer/django-user/login',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Fri, 10 Feb 2017 12:11:20 +0000

Comment: Can you add the code please, specially some part of myapp/views.py? did you do, `from django import forms`?

Comment: You should add your code, an explanation and what you have tried so far. It is very complicated for us helping you if there is no information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to import a module named "forms", which you either don't have installed or doesn't exist.

Try removing `import forms` from the top of your code.

I have no experience with Django but a quick search brings up a [forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) which may do what you're after.